# Array required but arraylist <int[]> found

Tags: java

No comprendo el porqué de este error:

```
// Método para obtener las propiedades del jugador 
    public ArrayList<int[]> obtenerPropiedadesJugador (){ // MIRAR
       int i = 0;
       boolean pertenece = false;
       ArrayList <int[]> propiedades_JA = new ArrayList ();

       for (Casilla casilla: tablero.getCasillas()){
            for(TituloPropiedad propiedad: jugadorActual.getPropiedades()){
                if(casilla.getTituloPropiedad() == propiedad)
                    pertenece = true;
            }
          if (pertenece){
              propiedades_JA [i]= casilla.getNumeroCasilla();
          }
       }
       return propiedades_JA;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Dónde te da el error?

Comment: me da error en la parte de propiedades_JA [i] = casilla.getNumeroCasilla();

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida. Muestra tu clase `Casilla`, sobre todo el método `getNumeroCasilla()`.

Answer (score 1):

A pesar de su nombre, **`ArrayList` no es un array** y no funciona como tal, es solo una implementación de `List` que internamente usa un array.

Así pues, el operador `[]` que se aplica a los arrays no es aplicable a `propiedades_JA` tal como está definido; puedes usar los métodos de `ArrayList`.

Al definir

```
ArrayList <int[]> propiedades_JA = new ArrayList<>(); //supongo que en el código estará el <>, porque si no no compila.
```

lo que dices es que `propiedades_JA` es un `ArrayList`, y que cada elemento del `ArrayList` será un array de *ints*(`int[]`).

Así que probablemente lo que quieres es

```
int propiedades_JA[] = new int[X]; // con X siendo el total de elementos de tablero.getCasillas().
```

Naturalmente, también tendrás que cambiar el tipo que retornas.

En otro orden de cosas, supongo que no incrementas `i` dentro del bucle porque se te ha olvidado.